# Can't Get Ubuntu Desktop Working on Ubuntu Server [Stuck With Guest Account]

Tags: server, login, gui

I've tried multiple re-installs and I've tried Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit and 14.04 64 bit. I always end up with a login screen with only a guest account.

The steps I take:

login as root

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

[image]

If I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and then type `startx`

Ah, on 15.10 I'd just get a cursor with an X on the background. In 14.04 I can actually open a terminal. I guess this is better than nothing but is there any way to unlock the full desktop?

[image]

Thanks for your assistance!

-CausingUnderflows

Comment: What are the UIDs of your regular account(s) on the server  (e.g. `id -u`)?

Comment: id -u returns 0

Comment: That would be the `root` account - on Ubuntu you should have a at least one non-account that belongs to the `sudo` group, and has UID >= 1000 (which is the default threshold for being listed on the lightdm login screen).

Comment: @steeldriver: Could you please add that as an answer? Preferably with (links to) instructions how to create such a user.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I had to create an additional user account aside from the root account I was logging in with into the terminal.

I got back into the terminal and followed the following instructions found on this website:
http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/07/how-to-create-new-user-account-from.html

---

Get to the terminal and run this command to create a new user:

**sudo useradd *username***

Replace "username" with the username you want to create.

Now assign a password for this new user with this command:

**sudo passwd *username***

Create now a home directory for this new user with this command (I named the directory the same as the username):

**sudo mkdir /home/*username***

Run now this command to change the owner of /home/username to this new user:

**sudo chown *username* /home/*username***

Now grant access to this new user to /home/username with this command:

**sudo chgrp *username* /home/*username***

You have now successfully created a new user. This user account will begin to appear in the login window at Ubuntu startup. If you want to grant this user root privileges (user can execute "sudo" commands), which is not a recommended step (be careful), then use this command from the Terminal:

**sudo adduser *username* sudo**

Comment: That formatting had some errors please correct them (remove astericks beside username)